# Substituting values of one column from a list of corresponding values

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I want to replace the entries in one column of file input *A.txt* by the list given in *B.txt* in corresponding order

For example

*A.txt* is **tab delimited** but in a column values are separated by comma
need to change one of entries of that column values say `P=`

```
1 X y Z Q=Alpha,P=beta,O=Theta
2 x a b Q=Alpha,P=beta,O=Theta
3 y b c Q=Alpha,P=beta,O=Theta
4 a b c Q=Alpha,P=beta,O=Theta
5 x y z Q=Alpha,P=beta,O=Theta
```

*B.txt* is

```
1 gamma
2 alpha
3 alpha
4 gamma
5 alpha
```

now reading each entry in *A.txt* and replace `P=` with the corresponding line values in *B.txt*

Output:

```
1 X y Z Q=Alpha,P=gamma,O=Theta
2 x a b Q=Alpha,P=alpha,O=Theta
3 y b c Q=Alpha,P=alpha,O=Theta
4 a b c Q=Alpha,P=gamma,O=Theta
5 x y z Q=Alpha,P=alpha,O=Theta
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please spend a little time searching Stack Overflow. This question gets asked frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming A.txt and B.txt are sorted on the first column, you can first `join` both files and then perform the replacement within a specified field using `sed`:

For example:

```
join -t $'\t' -j 1 A.txt B.txt | sed 's/,P=.*,\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/,P=\2,\1/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have sed write you a sed script, e.g.:

```
sed 's:^:/^:; s: :\\b/s/P=[^,]+/P=:; s:$:/:' B.txt
```

Output:

```
/^1\b/s/P=[^,]+/P=gamma/
/^2\b/s/P=[^,]+/P=alpha/
/^3\b/s/P=[^,]+/P=alpha/
/^4\b/s/P=[^,]+/P=gamma/
/^5\b/s/P=[^,]+/P=alpha/
```

Pipe it into a second sed:

```
sed 's:^:/^:; s: :\\b/s/P=[^,]+/P=:; s:$:/:' B.txt | sed -r -f - A.txt
```

Output:

```
1 X y Z Q=Alpha,P=gamma,O=Theta
2 x a b Q=Alpha,P=alpha,O=Theta
3 y b c Q=Alpha,P=alpha,O=Theta
4 a b c Q=Alpha,P=gamma,O=Theta
5 x y z Q=Alpha,P=alpha,O=Theta
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
awk '{getline b < "B.txt" split(b, a, FS)} -F "," {sub(/beta/, a[2]); print}' A.txt
```